# What is the proper term for a manufacturer of charcuteries?

Tags: terminology, french

I’m looking for the term for a business that takes raw meats from a slaughterhouse and refines them into charcuteries.

Comment: Sausage maker? Meat processor? Oscar-Meyer or Swift clone?

Comment: Are you looking for a word that would only apply to pork meat? Which [charcuterie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie) usually does.  If not meat processor is as @tchrist says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original guilds producing charcuterie were known as *charcutiers*.